# Loading groups of dependencies in Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, single-page-application

Webpack makes it really easy to bundle things together, and also asynchronously requiring single chunks.

However I can't quite work out how to delay requiring a set of dependencies needed by only a few parts of my app.

Since it's an SPA, I'd like to avoid using a `<script>` tag and have it load a set of larger (namely brace, esprima, lodash etc) dependencies when the user reaches the relevant parts of the app.

This is similar to the vendor split approach, except I only need the essential modules for navigation, signup, login etc. When using chunks out the box it duplicates these dependencies for each chunk, so they are common dependencies - but I'd like to have more than one common bundle; and be able to load it asynchronously when needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is called code splitting.  ([Webpack Code Splitting](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html))  Take a look at the Webpack site for a "brief" breakdown of how it works.  Most of the tutorials out there reference code splitting for critical path rendering, but the concept is the same and should be applicable for your situation.

I would recommend creating an entry for the your dependency bundles, and then reference that withing each module.  While you should theoretically be able to just pull in dependencies for each module independent of the "bundled dependencies", I have ran into issues with webpack where dependencies are reinitialized when referenced by separate bundles, which causes issues for dependencies that are meant to be singletons.